# Projectile Direction Unity

Tags: unity, c#, projectile-physics

I want to shoot a projectile in the direction the gun is facing.

With my current script it only shoots vertically. (I can also make it go horizontally but that's it).

This is my `GunController` class:

```
public Transform guntip;
public GameObject bullet;

float fireRate = 0.5f;
float nextFire = 0f;

void Update ()
{
    //playershooting
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Fire1") > 0)
    {
     fireRocket();
    }       
}

void fireRocket() 
{
    if(Time.time > nextFire)
    {
        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

        Instantiate(bullet, guntip.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 0))); 
    }
}
```

This is my `ProjectileController` class:

```
Rigidbody2D MyRB;
public float rocketSpeed;

 void Awake()
{
    MyRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    MyRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 1) * rocketSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse); // explosive force, change vector 2 for horizontal shooting

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Instantiate(bullet, guntip.position, guntip.rotation);
```

You need to inherit rotation of guntip to make bullets face that way.

---

To make bullet go towards the direction it's facing, if your 2D setup is top-down:

```
 MyRB.AddForce(transform.up * rocketSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

If your 2D setup is side-scroller:

```
 MyRB.AddForce(transform.right * rocketSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Comment: Thanks it is facing the right direction, but it is not moving, like before.

Comment: @AJ123 Try increasing `rocketSpeed` value.

Comment: It faces the right way but it always goes vertical.

Comment: Do you understand what this does?    `MyRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 1) * rocketSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);`  

Its taken from your code, so you should.

Why would your projectile go in any other direction than vertical?  That is how you wrote it.

Comment: I know, but how do I make it go the direction it's facing

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: With this solution use,  `MyRB.AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(0, 1) * rocketSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);` . As you are getting the orientation from the guntip, you have to add force in local/relative direction.

Comment: Can I use `RayCastHit2D` for that. If so can you please tell me how. because the projectile is still not going the right way.

Comment: @AJ123 Check the edit out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Awake()` method at `ProjectileController` class should be like:

```
void Awake()
{
    MyRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    Vector2 direction = GameObject.Find("Gun").GetComponenet<GunController>().guntip.position - transform.position; //Get a direction vector to fire the bullet at.

    direction.Normalized(); // direction vector normalized to magnitude 1

    MyRB.AddForce(direction * rocketSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

And Instantiation in `GunController()` should be like:

```
void fireRocket()
{
    if(Time.time > nextFire)
    {
        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

        Instantiate(bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity); 
    }
}
```

You need a direction from `GunController` class's `guntip`. Name the gun object as "Gun" (or change in code) and need to get the gun tip position so that you can get a direction to shoot the projectile at. When we are subtracting `projectile`'s position vector from `guntip`'s position vector, we get a direction from projectile's current position to `guntip`'s position which is the direction to shoot projectile. But it has some magnitude in it. So we have to make the magnitude to 1 so that it doesn't effect the force you are about to apply on it. That's why `Normalized()` is used on the direction so the direction vector is now unit vector with just direction in it(magnitude 1). Then `AddForce()` on that direction.

Comment: that does not work.

Comment: What the result? Have you put guntip as Gun object's child?